# What is the fastest way to make sure a str is a int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make sure a string is a int in Python 3.6, here is four ways. But I don't know which one is the fastest, or could someone give me a faster one?

```
import re

input_value = '012345678901'


def test1(value_str):
    value_str = value_str.lstrip('0')
    try:
        value_int = int(value_str)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return len(str(value_int)) == len(value_str)


def test2(value_str):
    return re.match('\d+$', value_str) is not None


def test3(value_str):
    num_set = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
    for i in value_str:
        if i not in num_set:
            return False
    return True


def test4(value_str):
    return value_str.isdigit()
```

I tested them with `timeit`, here is the result:

```
run 1000000 times test1: 0.920672991022002
run 1000000 times test2: 1.1261013330076821
run 1000000 times test3: 0.8881843989947811
run 1000000 times test4: 0.16987622604938224
```

---

Edit notes:

After testing many times, I know this:

1. for unsigned number, `test4` is the fastest.
2. for signed number, if it includes`'-'`or`'+'` like `'-123'`, `test2` is always slow, others depends on how to remove the sign. I'm still not sure.

And the `lstrip('0')` in `test1` is just for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496390/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-make-sure-a-str-is-a-int/52498764?noredirect=1#comment91970004_52497624)

Comment: Test3 looks the fastest. Maybe you can speed up Test1, by removing the `.lstrip('0')` because `int('00001') == 1` anyway, and same thing for the `bool()`.

Comment: What about simply `value_str.isdigit()`?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know which one is fastest? Don't you understand the `timeit` results?

Comment: @schwobaseggl, True. Technically, [it's not he same](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) but for most practical purposes may be fine.

Comment: @schwobaseggl  value_str.isdigit() will not work with negative numbers right?

Comment: Note that you should also time your functions for different kinds of non-integer strings, as the time needed to identify them as wrong can (and does, here) hugely differ.

Comment: All of your test functions have still room for improvement so I wouldn't say that it was a fair comparison. For example you can remove the `if/else` branches from `test2`, also you can pre-compile the regex. For `test3` `all` or `any` together with `map` may be faster. Then `test1` contains unnecessary function calls such as `bool()`.

Comment: @PROTOCOL Nope, it does not. But the OP's methods don't work with negatives either.

Comment: As @PROTOCOL said:  `'42'.isdigit()` -> `True` and  `'-42'.isdigit()` -> `False`

Comment: @martineau According to the regex of `test2` the OP apparently only considers positive integers.

Comment: In `test3` you need `num_set = {'-', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}` to account for negative numbers

Comment: @martineau initially a typo but fixed in 10 secs. I've included `'-'` in the set

Comment: @roganjosh: That's better—however strings like `42-13` aren't valid integers.

Comment: @martineau it would only ever need to executed at-most twice because the first condition would have to evaluate to `True` before anything after `and` is evaluated (so we know we're already dealing with a non-numeric character), and then you could `break` the loop. But even that wouldn't work, because `-42-13` would be `True`. `for i, letter in enumerate(value_str):` and `if letter not in num_set and i > 0 and letter != '-':` would probably be required to close all loopholes

Comment: @a_guest: Just because one of the OP's test functions is wrong doesn't mean that's what they want or intended. If it's what they desire, it should be indicated in the title and/or question itself.

Comment: @martineau the first part of my reply is nonsense sorry, but the approach at the end should work. We also need to consider that "fastest" is nonsense if the approach is broken :)

Comment: @roganjosh: I think covering all the loopholes is going to slow it down too much for it to be much of a contender for fastest. If I'm wrong, post an answer.

Comment: @martineau I'm on phone so can't test but what is the `return` for `test1` checking for? Can't it just `return True`?

Comment: Woko: Speed isn't the only, nor necessarily the primary concern. Validity is also very important. Also, as @ZaphoOxx said, if you're dong the test before converting the string to an `int`, function `test1()` might be the best overall approach (without the unneeded stripping of leading zeros).

Answer (score 1):

Hi an alternative could be the following one:

```
def test4(value_str):
    negative = value_str.find("-")
    if negative > 0:
        return False
    elif negative == 0:
        value_str = value_str[1:]
    return value_str.isdigit()
```

The results on my machine are:

- test1: 0.798348898
- test2: 0.9424690370000001
- test3: 0.5995461930000001
- test4: 0.29526326800000025

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I edited the answer to take into account negative values

Answer (score 1):

I took the code and ran it a couple of times, it seems that test3 is the fastest. Even thought I cleaned up a little bit test1 and I was able to accomplish a similar speed to test3, sometimes better. Here I post your code, plus the test I added:

```
import re
import timeit


def test1():
    value_str = '-012345678901'
    value_str = value_str.lstrip('0')
    try:
        value_int = int(value_str)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return bool(len(str(value_int)) == len(value_str))

print(timeit.timeit(test1, number=10000))


def test2():
    value_str = '-012345678901'
    if re.match('[\d]+$', value_str) is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(timeit.timeit(test2, number=10000))


def test3():
    value_str = '-012345678901'
    num_set = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
    for i in value_str:
        if i not in num_set:
            return False
    return True

print(timeit.timeit(test3, number=10000))


def test4():
    value_str = '-012345678901'
    try:
        int(value_str)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

print(timeit.timeit(test4, number=10000))


def test5():
    value_str = '-012345678901'
    negative = value_str.find("-")
    if negative > 0:
        return False
    elif negative == 0:
        value_str = value_str[1:]
    return value_str.isdigit()

print(timeit.timeit(test5, number=10000))
```

I also compared it to the answer given before mine, I renamed his function to test5. Test4 proved to be a faster alternative.

Finally, please notice that the functions are self-contained. I did this in order to run it successfully with timeit, since this is a speed test one of these functions may be picked and reverted back in order to use the parameter again. Hope this helps!

```
test1 = 0.01150935102486983
test2 = 0.014068655029404908
test3 = 0.006000193010549992
test4 = 0.004028786963317543
test5 = 0.007849656976759434
```

Comment: You can try `test4('   123')` and it returns `True`, that's why I compare length in `test1()`. But it's helpful, thanks~

Answer (score 0):

May be fastest way is to use pythonic way of checking whether it is a alphabetical string or not.

```
import timeit
def test():
    a = "123"
    return a.isalpha()

print(timeit.timeit(test, number=10000))

0.001194985743579478
```

isalpha will return True if a string contains only alphabetical characters. 
It will return False is string contains any numerical or alphanumerical characters

EDIT:

```
import timeit
def test():
   a = "123"
   a = a.lstrip("-")
   return a.isdigit()

print(timeit.timeit(test, number=10000))

0.0019427791237219235
```

Comment: I'm trying to check numbers, maybe you mean `isdigit()`?

Comment: @Woko no, as mentioned in comments if you use isdigit() then for "-123" will return False. isdigit() will not identify negative numbers. So I think it is better to use isalpha()

Comment: But `'123'.isalpha()` returns False, `'abc123'.isalpha()` returns False, `'abc'.isalpha()` returns True. So I'm confused about what you mean.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have edited my code. Please check