# Why is the built-in string.isdigit() implementation faster than my own implementation?

Tags: python, performance

I'm studying algorithms and I have a question about the difference between `isdigit()` and `my_isdigit()`.

```py
import time


def my_isdigit(str):
    s = set(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'])
    for x in str:
        if x not in s:
            return False
    return True


test_str = '1234567890' * 10000000
start = time.time()
test_str.isdigit()
print(time.time() - start)  # 0.21125102043151855


start = time.time()
my_isdigit(test_str)
print(time.time() - start)  # 2.169161319732666
```

Why is `isdigit()` much faster than mine?

I saw [What is the fastest way to make sure a str is a int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496390/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-make-sure-a-str-is-a-int) but I cannot get the reason.

Is it the difference between C and Python? Or is my code bad?

Comment: `isdigit` is implemented in C, to the best of my knowledge

Comment: The built-in `str.isdigit` is implemented in C, which is much faster than Python. Also, you're unnecessarily building the same set in every call.

Comment: @blhsing Not to mention using `set([..])`, which involves building a list, finding the global name `set`, invoking it, etc. instead of using a set literal. :)

Comment: If you wanted to check if a character is not between `'0'` and `'9'`, you could use `if not ('0' <= x <= '9')`. You don't need a set for that.

Comment: For the curious, [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/310f94871a923f6cf3dc9259e732ce2376578b26/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11417-L11453) is the C `isdigit` implementation; the helpers that do the actual work [are here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/310f94871a923f6cf3dc9259e732ce2376578b26/Objects/unicodectype.c#L118-L133).

Comment: @khelwood Should note that in an Unicode world, that's not what `isdigit` does: `>>> '፫'.isdigit()`: `True` (`U+136B ETHIOPIC DIGIT THREE`)

Comment: @AKX Yes, that's why I specified *If you wanted to check if a character is not between '0' and '9'*.

Comment: Yep – but also OP's `my_isdigit` is decidedly not an analogue of `str.isdigit` :)

Comment: @khelwood Heh, by the way: that implementation is slower than OP's original set code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builtin functions such as `str.isdigit()` are implemented in C (when using CPython), and C is a lot faster than Python.

You can find the C code for `str.isdigit` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/310f94871a923f6cf3dc9259e732ce2376578b26/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11417-L11453); it calls [these helpers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/310f94871a923f6cf3dc9259e732ce2376578b26/Objects/unicodectype.c#L118-L133) which look up the character class in Python's built-in Unicode database.

Since `str`s are Unicode, and Unicode aware, this leads into a possibly surprising result: characters that aren't *Latin* numerals are `digit` too:

```
>>> '፫'.isdigit()
True
```

I tested a couple of different approaches (from this thread and otherwise): even faster than `str.isdigit()`, and limited to Latin numerals only is to encode the Unicode string into ASCII bytes first, then run `isdigit` on it (which [is a different implementation](https://cs.github.com/python/cpython/blob/4bed0db7c222f8df1b4e31107c0305214caf3f56/Objects/bytes_methods.c?q=_Py_bytes_isdigit#L147-L174) that [uses a simpler lookup table](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4bed0db7c222f8df1b4e31107c0305214caf3f56/Python/pyctype.c?q=_Py_ctype_table#L5) for the 256 possible ASCII bytes):

```
def bytes_isdigit(s):
    return s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').isdigit()

# ...
name='my_isdigit' iters=1 time=2.788 iters_per_sec=0.36
name='builtin' iters=5 time=0.425 iters_per_sec=11.75
name='daweo' iters=1 time=1.011 iters_per_sec=0.99
name='khelwood' iters=1 time=4.837 iters_per_sec=0.21
name='bytes_isdigit' iters=5 time=0.309 iters_per_sec=16.18
```

Comment: Another fairly fast one: `return not s.translate(s.maketrans('', '', '0123456789'))`

Answer (score 1):

c language is compiler type language and also very close to machine level code/language, hence the run time for c is far more less when compared to python which is interpreted language.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I want to note that your *test suite* is extremely limited, you are considering solely case when string is made of digits and not where there is mix of digits and non-digits and solely non-digits.

You should find [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) useful, note that it can easily repeat given test many times. `timeit` is part of standard library.

Regarding your function I would ameloriate it following way

```
def my_isdigit(s):
    digits = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'}
    return digits.issuperset(s)
```

Observe that I do not use `str` as it is built-in, you should not overshadow built-name variables unless really neccessary. I use set arithmetics to find if *set of digits* is superset of *set of characters in s*. I also used set literal rather than `set` function to convert list into set.